# Error "object of type 'NoneType' has no len()" on list explicitely created with list()

Tags: python, built-in

I am new to Python and for my AI class I was trying to do an Huffman encoding program for strings. For that, I need to build an optimized weigthed tree. Thing is, I'm trying to call the `len()` function on a variable explicitly created with the `list()` built-in function, but it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong ?

Here's the code:

```py
def opti(text):
        occ = occurences(text)
        occ = dict(sorted(occ.items(), key=lambda item: item[1]))
        l_n = list(occ.items())
        while len(l_n) > 1:
                n1 = l_n.pop(0)
                n2 = l_n.pop(0)
                n = Noeud(n1[1] + n2[1], n1, n2)
                l_n.append((n, n.valeur))
                l_n = l_n.sort(key=lambda tup: tup[1])
        return l_n

class Noeud:
        def __init__(self, value, left, right):
                self.value = value
                self.left = left
                self.right = right
```

If I print the variable `l_n` I'm clearly getting a list so I don't understand why this isn't working. I've already tried looking for an answer on other topics but the answer mostly were about other functions modifying the type to `NoneType` whereas here I'm clearly using the list constructor function.

The function `occurences` returns a dictionary containing the number of occurences of each character in a string, if that matters.

Comment: The fact that a variable *originally* referred to a list doesn't mean it *still does*. When you encounter a bug like this, try to figure out when the variable started referring to a new object. (Hint: it has to be an assignment, and there's only one other assignment statement assigning to `l_n` besides the initialization.)

Comment: `l_n = l_n.sort(key=lambda tup: tup[1])` this line is the problem, just change it to `l_n.sort(key=lambda tup: tup[1])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
l_n = l_n.sort(key=lambda tup: tup[1])
```

Here `sort()` function sorts list inplace. Hence it retuns None.

Instead try this:

`l_n = sorted(l_n, key=lambda tup: tup[1])`

OR Just this:
`l_n.sort(key=lambda tup: tup[1])`

Comment: Thanks I was so focused on why it wouldn't work with this that I didn't realize it could change afterward in the loop. In my mind it caused the issue right when entering the loop. Thanks you very much